# How to Hook an application to a particular key?

Tags: c#

I want my application should be start when a particular key is pressed??

Comment: Refer this [link](http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-5034562.html) to create hotkey for application

Answer (score 1):

Use an application like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). I think the C# tag is irrelevant - you want Windows to fire up a given app on a given key press, so just find a tool that does this for you.

Comment: I would suggest AutoIt v3, but it's purpose is exactly the same as AutoHotkey so use either.

Comment: No axe to grind personally - feel free to edit into my answer. I don't use any of these tools myself.